# Best way to handle non-existent sub-documents in MongoDB query results

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I know this question has been asked before in some shape or form but I am looking for the best way to handle query results without a lot of if statements.

Let's say I am looking for a product (sub-document) in a package (document)

```
Packages.find({_id : req.body.packId, "products._id" : req.body.prodId})
   .exec(function(err, result){
     if(err) throw err;

    // make sure the result array exists and is not empty

     if(result && result.length > 0) {

       // make sure product array exists and is not empty

        if(result.products && result.products.length > 0){
           res.json(result);
           }
          }
        });
```

I noticed I cannot do:

```
if(result.products.length > 0)
```

If there is no product, node will crash since it cannot determine 'length' of undefined.

My question is: Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know Mongo, but maybe you can use $gt (greater than).
Something like: ME.find({ pictures: { $gt: [] } })

Comment: As long as your `req.body.prodId` doesn't contain `null` the checks you are talking about here are useless because your `products` field will be there (and will contain an array unless you have documents where the `products` field is not an array and still has an `_id` field).

Comment: Products are defined in the model as an array. I think if there are no products we don't just have an empty array we have no array at all. That's why if(result.products.length > 0) is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are already checking the products_id, so it should never be null if it is returned.

Another way you could do it is by checking that the field is populated in the query.

```
db.Packages.find({ "products.": { $exists: true, $ne: null } })
```

You can make the check in the query itself so that you don't have to check in code.

Comment: Thanks. That's was exactly what I was looking for.